# Port mapping is not working for docker on mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to run docker container for spring boot application however I am not able to access the application.

I am using docker on mac with the following version

**Mac OS Mojave version**

```
10.14.3 (18D109)
```

**Docker version on mac:**

```
anhs-MBP:spring-boot-with-fargate anhtrang$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

I have checked the container logs and spring boot application started normally

**Container logs:**

```
019-08-12 01:08:42.885  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2019-08-12 01:08:43.026  INFO 6 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-12 01:08:43.045  INFO 6 --- [           main] c.e.s.SpringBootWithFargateApplication   : Started SpringBootWithFargateApplication in 8.06 seconds (JVM running for 9.107)
```

**Command to start docker container:**

```
anhs-MBP:spring-boot-with-fargate anhtrang$ docker run -d -p 8080:8080 anhtrang/spring-boot-with-farget:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I also tried starting the spring boot application outside of container it's working perfectly. I just don't understand why its not able to expose the port

My GitHub repo:

https://github.com/anhtv08/spring-boot-with-fargate

Appreciate for any quick help

Comment: Have you looked at macOS's built-in firewall?

Comment: Firewall has been turned off. would you able to have a look in my code repo @Dai

Comment: It probably be problem with my mac. I don't know exactly yet. I have spun up `ec2 instance` in aws and have it working.

Comment: I just rebuilt the docker image and have it working now for both mac and linux. Dont  really know what I have done wrongly earlier